# Getting "Bad Request. Invalid request header"

Tags: vbscript, httprequest

Below is the code I use for VBScript to send an HTTP request.

```
Option Explicit

Dim objHTTP, url, Hpost
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")    
url = "http://localhost:8080/xyz/processKey?key=abcd"
objHTTP.open "POST", url, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objHTTP.send
WScript.Echo objHTTP.responseText
```

Error:

> HTTP 400 Bad Request
>   Content-Length must be > 0

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Set http = CreateObject("Microsoft.XmlHttp")`? I know it's mostly case insensitive but I don't think that extends to objects.

Comment: It does not matter. I tried both "Microsoft.XmlHttp" and ""Microsoft.XMLHTTP" but still getting same 400 erro.

Comment: `CreateObject` is not case-sensitive, but `Microsoft.XMLHTTP` is outdated and should be replaced by `Msxml2.XMLHttp`. The code worked for me either way, though. What does the server log say about the failed requests?

Comment: I do not have access to the server.I replaced it with Msxml2.XMLHttp but still getting 400 error code , Bad Request.Content-Length must be >0

Comment: I quess that `send` method requires a parameter, cf. [How To Submit Form Data by Using XMLHTTP or ServerXMLHTTP Object](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/290591).

Comment: From the URL looks almost like you are trying to do a `HTTP GET` request `?key=abcd`, if however you are meant to be using `POST` then change your send line to `objHTTP.send "key=abcd"` so the data is passed in the body of the message rather then the URL.

Comment: the error message is stating you need another request header, Content-Length. --> `.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", #`

Comment: @WhiteHat Yes but the reason the `Content-Length` header isn't being passed is because the request body is 0 bytes and `POST` expects a request body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edit: Adopting  @Lankymart's comments]

Your request doesn't appear to be a pure "HTTP POST" or "HTTP GET" request.

For a "HTTP POST" request:

- Parameters shouldn't be in the URL, it should be in the body
- Seems the server is expecting a Content-Length

Example:

```
Option Explicit
Dim objHTTP, url, param
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")    
url = "http://localhost:8080/xyz/processKey"
param = "key=abcd"
objHTTP.open "POST", url, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objHTTP.send param
WScript.Echo objHTTP.responseText
```

For a "HTTP GET" request

- Parameters must be embedded in the URL
- Send must be blank

Example:

```
Option Explicit
Dim objHTTP, url, param
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")    
url = "http://localhost:8080/xyz/processKey"
param = "key=abcd"
objHTTP.open "GET", url + "?" + param, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objHTTP.send
WScript.Echo objHTTP.responseText
```

Comment: I tried HTTP Post but getting error saying that "The download of the specified resource has failed"

Comment: This is HTTP Post request only.

Comment: Sorry , all of you were right. It was http get request and i tried HTTP Get version and it worked fine ..

Comment: You don't need to specify an argument on `.Send` when doing a `GET` request you also don't need to explicitly set `Content-Length` using `.setRequestHeader()` because the length is inferred from the `.Send "..."` argument when doing a `POST` request.

Comment: @rrrppp How can you not know what the endpoint expects when you are running this on `localhost`?

Comment: This is actual we are hitting server with IP , so i just type localhost. I don't have enough informations about the request.